# How to use EasyMock in android

Tags: android, unit-testing, easymock

I use easymock-3.2.jar in my android test project.
I find it in its Home:

```
2013-07-11: EasyMock 3.2 is available. Add @Mock annotations and Android support.
```

However , I got exception when I use it.

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.easymock.EasyMock`

I googled a lot , and add

```
dexmaker-1.0.jar
objenesis-1.2.jar
cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar or cglib-2.2.jar
```

But the exception still be there.Who can help me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track. I wonder if you're using it incorrectly? Perhaps add a test where you're using EasyMock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the library

```
easymock-3.2.jar
dexmaker-1.0.jar
dexmaker-mockito-1.0.jar
```

in tests/libs. And it will work.

Be careful , it's in tests/libs , not in tests/lib. 
It will throw

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.easymock.EasyMock
```

if you position them in tests/lib.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to get EasyMock. You can get the latest version from Easymock’s download page. Choose the latest version and you will get a zip file. You only need easymock-3.2.jar (3.2 will change depending on the version you choose). You will also need dexmaker for Easymock to work on Android. You can get the jar from Dexmaker’s website. Once you have both jar files put them in /tests/libs. Now you have EasyMock available in your tests.

for more detail follow below link
http://ncona.com/2013/11/writing-unit-test-for-android-with-easymock/

Comment: I already tried this method method , however , it didn't work.